# Select query returning 1 result instead of 3 because of AVG

Tags: php, mysql, average

The select query below returns 1 row when it should be 3. I am pretty sure it is because of the AVG(k.sumtotal) field.

If I rewrite the query and take out that AVG(k.sumtotal) column and take out the FROM inv_ratings AS k, I get my 3 rows.

I can't figure out why this table (inv_ratings) or this AVG(k.sumtotal) column restrict the number of rows to 1. I looked online for hours trying to find information about returning results using the AVG clause and didn't find much. Do I have to use a group by clause, I tried that and only get errors.

```
$p = "SELECT i.invention_id, i.inv_title, i.date_submitted, i.category_id,"
    . " i.approved, c.category_id, c.category, u.image_name, AVG(k.sumtotal)"
    . " FROM inv_ratings AS k INNER JOIN inventions AS i USING (invention_id)"
    . " INNER JOIN categories AS c USING (category_id)"
    . " INNER JOIN images AS u USING (invention_id)"
    . " WHERE c.category_id = $cat AND i.approved = 'approved'"
    . " HAVING u.image_name < 2"
    . " ORDER BY date_submitted"
    . " DESC LIMIT $start, $display";

$q = mysqli_query($dbc, $p) or trigger_error("Query: $p\n<br />mysqli Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Comment: You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Do you want one average per section, or a unique average which will be identical on every row ?

Comment: can you phrase it for me, I tried countless times to get that to work and it won't work

Comment: I want an average of all the ratings for each individual invention_id.

Answer (score 0):

You are running into one of MySQL's gotchas:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

I hate that MySQL ever allows this syntax because it only causes confusion.  But what you probably want is (to use MySQL's hackish behavior, please note that if there are multiple values for any of the fields besides invention_id or sumtotal, you get a random value from that column):

```
$p = "SELECT i.invention_id, i.inv_title, i.date_submitted, i.category_id,"
. " i.approved, c.category_id, c.category, u.image_name, AVG(k.sumtotal)"
. " FROM inv_ratings AS k INNER JOIN inventions AS i USING (invention_id)"
. " INNER JOIN categories AS c USING (category_id)"
. " INNER JOIN images AS u USING (invention_id)"
. " WHERE c.category_id = $cat AND i.approved = 'approved'"
. " GROUP BY i.invention_id "
. " HAVING u.image_name < 2"
. " ORDER BY date_submitted"
. " DESC LIMIT $start, $display";
```

Or, to not use MySQL's hackish behavior:

```
$p = "SELECT i.invention_id, i.inv_title, i.date_submitted, i.category_id,"
. " i.approved, c.category_id, c.category, u.image_name, AVG(k.sumtotal)"
. " FROM inv_ratings AS k INNER JOIN inventions AS i USING (invention_id)"
. " INNER JOIN categories AS c USING (category_id)"
. " INNER JOIN images AS u USING (invention_id)"
. " WHERE c.category_id = $cat AND i.approved = 'approved'"
. " GROUP BY i.invention_id, i.inv_title, i.date_submitted, i.category_id,"
. " i.approved, c.category_id, c.category, u.image_name "
. " HAVING u.image_name < 2"
. " ORDER BY date_submitted"
. " DESC LIMIT $start, $display";
```

Comment: `group by` should be after `where`.